# Как передать URI из одной активити в другую?

Tags: java, android, activity

Добрый день. Я новичок и нуждаюсь в помощи.

Написал программу, в которой пользователь выбирает изображение из галереи или снимает по камере и это изображение отображается в `MainActivity`, затем нужно эту картинку передать на другую `Activity`.

Написал так, но во время отправки приложение вылетает.
Помогите исправить пожалуйста.

Вот здесь я уже получил изображение и поставил в `ImageView` и хочу передать, но выводится исключение `NullPointerException`:
Main:

```
Uri selectedImage;
ImageView preview;
ImageButton gallery;
ImageButton camera;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    gallery = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.gallery_button);
    camera = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.camera_button);
    preview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.selected_image);

    camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent takepic = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(takepic, 0);
        }
    });

    gallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent choosegal = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(choosegal, 1);
        }
    });

    preview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent choose = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Second_Activity.class);
                choose.putExtra("img", selectedImage.toString());
                startActivity(choose);

        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int req, int res, Intent imagereturn) {
    super.onActivityResult(req, res, imagereturn);
    switch (req) {
        case 0:
            if (res == RESULT_OK) {
                selectedImage = imagereturn.getData();
                preview.setImageURI(selectedImage);
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            if (res == RESULT_OK) {
                selectedImage = imagereturn.getData();
                preview.setImageURI(selectedImage);
            }
            break;
    }


}
```

Second:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    ImageView image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ramka);
    //
}
```

Comment: Покажите саму ошибку.

Comment: choose.putExtra("img", selectedImage.toString()); во время этого метода приложение останавливается, прошел по дебагу а там увидел что вылетает исключение. если хотите могу показать весь код

Comment: и по этому я здесь. можете помочь ?

Comment: вам нужно передать `Bitmap` или какой объект?

Comment: selectedImage объект Uri

Comment: если URI, то передаете правильно, а как получаете? Вообще нужно больше кода: инициализация вашего selectedImage и как потом получаете в другой активити

Comment: ImageView image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ramka);
        String imageUriSource = getIntent().getStringExtra("img");
if (imageUriSource != null) {
    Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(imageUriSource);
    imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);

Comment: Получать надо так: `Uri imageUri = intent.getParcelableExtra("img");`

Comment: Добавил весь код под тему. посмотрите пожалуйста

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, чтобы передать объект `Uri` через `Intent` нужно при отправке конвертировать его в строку.

отправка:

```
intent.putExtra("img", selectedImage.toString());
```

получение в другой активити:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(extras.getString("img"));
```

или парселизировать сам URI.

отправка:

```
intent.putExtra("img", selectedImage);
```

получение:

```
Uri uri = intent.getParcelableExtra("img");
```

Comment: но здесь уже NullPointerException
и извините конечно за вопрос. но extras это какой обьект у меня в коде?

Comment: extras это метод, который передает/получает данные. В вашем коде вы передаете\получаете вообще непонятно что. Шлете путь до картинки (path), а получить пытаетесь число (int)

Comment: нет вашим способом тоже попробовал не получается. опять приложение остановливается

Comment: Тогда привидите свой код в вопросе в актуальное состояние, приложите стектрейс при падении и укажите строку на которой падает

Comment: я же указал )) вот здесь
 
choose.putExtra("img", selectedImage.toString());

Comment: в вашем коде в вопросе нет такой строки

Comment: preview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() вот здесь посмотрите сейчас.
пожалуйста помогите если сможете . 2 дня уже мучаюсь

Comment: В коде все правильно, единственное, почему может вылетать с NPE - на момент обращения `selectedImage` не инициализирован (ему не присвоено значение)

Comment: и как сделать это правильно?

Comment: Перед тем, как отправлять интент с URI, нужно, чтобы этот URI был получен.Перед отправкой убедитесь, что `selectedImage` содержит значение.

Comment: сейчас изменилось что то.
после startActivity(choose); пишет Frame is not available

Comment: снимите все брейкпойнты и перезапустите студию

Comment: Все я кажется понял. Спасибо вам за все